Lenovo flex 5 lid close doesn't suspend laptop on Ubunu 22.04 and Budgie
My Lenovo laptop flex 5 doesn't trigger suspend (or hibernate for that matter) although I have updated setting to following (removed comment):
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleListSwitchExternalPower=suspend

And of course restarted service (systemctl restart systemd-logind.service) and rebooted without luck.
Any thoughts why?
Thanks!
